# Analytical badge

Tags: support, badges

I have read the FAQ for the main site a few times, both by expanding all sections, and clicking expand all, and yet no badge. This has not been an issue for me on any other SE site (or even this meta site). Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: Give it a minute; sometimes the news takes a while to travel through the whole system.

Comment: It has been a day

Comment: You can have one of mine: ๏.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just [earned](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/268/guy-coder?tab=badges) it during my testing of this:

1. Start at [FAQ](https://cs.stackexchange.com/faq)
2. Click on each show more, but wait two seconds before clicking on the next one.
   The problem seems to come from the background fading once the section is expanded.

See: SO Meta [analytical-badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103797/analytical-badge) for more info.